# Seeking quoted string generator

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, quotes, magic-quotes

Does anyone know of a free website or program which will take a string and render it quoted with the appropriate escape characters?

Let's say, for instance, that I want to quote

```
It's often said that "devs don't know how to quote nested "quoted strings"".
```

And I would like to specify whether that gets enclosed in single or double quotes. I don't personally care for any escape character other than backslash, but other's might.

Comment: Any editor can do a search/replace, is that not enough?

Comment: Appropriate for what? The exact escaping convention that must be used depends on the language... Shell script? Perl? Php? Python? Tcl?

Comment: Can you explain your requirements better? You probably want to escape other characters... what if your string contains a backslash, newlines, or others? How will you use the string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so, I guess the answer is "no". Sorry, guys, but I didn't learn anything that I don't know. Probably my fault for not phrasing the question correctly.

+1 for everyone who posted

Answer (score 2):

If none of the double quotes of the string is already escaped, you can simply do:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");
```

Otherwise, you should check if it is already escaped and replace only if it isn't; You can use lookbehind for that. The following is what came to my mind first but it would fail for strings like `escaped backslash followed by quotes \\" :(`

```
str = str.replace(/(?<!\\)"/g, "\\\"");
```

The following makes sure that the second last character, if exists, is not a backslash.

```
str = str.replace(/(?<!(^|[^\\])\\)"/g, "\\\"");
```

Update: Just remembered that **JavaScript doesn't support look-behind**; you can use the same regex on a look-behind supporting regex engine like perl/php/.net etc.

Answer (score 2):

Any decent regex library in any decent programming language will have a function to do this - not that it's hard to write one yourself (as the other answers have indicated). So having a separate website or program to do it would be mostly useless.

- Perl has the [`quotemeta` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)
- PCRE's C++ wrapper has a function [`RE::QuoteMeta`](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) (warning: giant file at that link) which does the same thing
- PHP has [`preg_quote`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) if you're using Perl-compatible regexes
- Python's [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) has an `escape` function
- In Java, the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class has a [`quote` method](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String))
- Perl and most of the other regular expression engines based on Perl have metacharacters `\Q...\E`, meaning that whatever comes between `\Q` and `\E` is interpreted literally
- Most tools that use POSIX regular expressions (e.g. `grep`) have an option that makes them interpret their input as a literal string (e.g. `grep -F`)

Comment: These are all good suggestions, but it still depends on what the output will be used for: these will work for regular expressions, and sometimes for double-quoted strings, but generally not for single-quoted strings, for example...

Comment: Hmm, I think I misread the question as just asking about regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, for enclosing in single quotes:

```
import re
mystr = """It's often said that "devs don't know how to quote nested "quoted strings""."""
print("""'%s'""" % re.sub("'", r"\'", mystr))
```

Output:

```
'It\'s often said that "devs don\'t know how to quote nested "quoted strings"".'
```

You could easily adapt this into a more general form, and/or wrap it in a script for command-line invocation.